# IPv6 mapping the IP address on Xamarin app (C#)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to map my hard coded IP to IPv6 using the built in API "MapToIPv6"in C# (Xamarin.Forms App). So when I try to map the IP "55.179.56.24", I get "::ffff:55.179.56.24" back.

However when I test the new IPv6 mapped URL "http://[::ffff:55.179.56.24]:6005", I get "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname". (I am testing through Postman on my Windows 10 machine)

Till we get a host name we need to use this IP, and the apple always rejects the submission.

Any help would be much appreciated.

(Note : Above IP is not real, but just for the illustration)

#### EDIT:

In this blog from James there is a section called "Hard Coded IP Addresses". However I am unable to figure out how should resolve my issue

https://blog.xamarin.com/making-your-ios-apps-ipv6-ready/

Comment: Did you try your approach with another target? Lets say google or whatever?

Comment: No, I did not. As it is not a requirement for Google and google submission was successful.

Comment: Any help or at least a direction would be very much appreciated.